# How Edit data of an XML node with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to write some data in an existing local XML file with Javascript with some text from an Html page. Is it possible to change content of nodes?
Here is XML sample:

```
<Notepad>
    <Name>Player1</Name>
    <Notes>text1</Notes>
</Notepad>
```

I will get some more text from input and want to add it after "text1", but can't find a solution.

```js
function SaveNotes(content,player)
   {
   var xml = "serialize.xml";
   var xmlTree =  parseXml("<Notepad></Notepad>");
   var str = xmlTree.createElement("Notes");
  
           
   $(xmlTree).find("Notepad").find(player).append(str);
   $(xmlTree).find("Notes").find(player).append(content);
   var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlTree);
   
     
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to manipulate xml content or xml file :
[Update] 
Please check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Wpb/48/)

```
    var parseXml;

    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };

var xmlTree = parseXml("<root></root>");

function add_children(child_name, parent_name) {
    str = xmlTree.createElement(child_name);
    //strXML = parseXml(str);
    $(xmlTree).find(parent_name).append(str);
    $(xmlTree).find(child_name).append("hello");
    var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlTree);
    alert(xmlString);
}
add_children("apple", "root");
add_children("orange", "root");
add_children("lychee", "root");
```

you can use it for searching in xml as well as adding new nodes with content in it. (And sorry i dont know how to load xml from client side and display it.)
but this fiddle demo will be helpful in adding content in xml and searching in it.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: but it is not writing in a xml file.

Comment: I have a notepad part in a Html page which is saving notes about different players in an xml file. each time i enter the player name as an input, it has to find the previous notes from xml file, show them and add new notes to it and save it again in xml file.

Comment: I have updated my answer with "xml node searching and storing content in it". and sorry i dont know how to load xml and how to display it :(

Comment: I tried this code but no success. One question is it possible to use the find() like this : $(xmlTree).find("Notes").find(player).append(content);

Comment: no man , it works, please check this fiddle , i have created as per your function savenotes :: https://jsfiddle.net/82zbjutu/  and let me know if you want to modify it. :)

Comment: thanx man, the code is working, but the problem is writing in a XML file, which im not sure that its possible at all or not!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this on the client side you can parse your xml into a document object:

See 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML
and
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest2

And then manipulate it like you would the DOM of any html doc, e.g. createElement, appendChild etc.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Then to serialize it into a String again you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

**Persisting the data**

Writing to a local file is not possible in a cross-browser way. In IE you could use ActiveX to read/write file.

You could use cookies to store data on the client side, if your data keeps small enough.

In HTML5 you could use local storage, see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: and how i can write back in XML file?

Comment: where do you want this XML file to be? On your server or downloaded to the client?

Comment: on a client, its a local file. the whole story is that I have a notepad part in a Html page which is saving notes about different players in an xml file. each time i enter the player name as an input, it has to find the previous notes from xml file, show them and add new notes to it and save it again in xml file.

Comment: @adonis Persisting the data on the client side is an issue of its own. I have updated my answer to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanx for description, I am almost lost in my code!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these two package one to convert to json and when is finish the other to come back

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser